# Show that : $ \|A\|=\sup_{x^*\in B^*}{s(x^*|A)} $

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a Banach space and :
$$
\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)=\{A\subset X\, |\, A\,\text{is nonempty, weakly compact, convex\}}.
$$
Let  $A\in \mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$, we define the radius of $A$ by:
$$
\|A\|:=\sup_{x\in A}{\|x\|}
$$
Show that :
$$
\|A\|=\sup_{x^*\in B^*}{s(x^*|A)}
$$
with : ${s(x^*|A)}:=\sup_{x\in A}{\langle x^*,x\rangle}$ and $B^*$ is the unit ball of $X^*$.

**My effort:**

according to the definition of $ s (x^* | A) $, we have
$$
s (x^* | A) \leq \|x^*\|\|A\|
$$
Then : $s(x^*|A)\leq \|A\|$ for all $x^*\in B^*$, which implies : $\sup_{x^*\in B^*}{s(x^*|A)}\leq \|A\|$.

My problem is to show other inequality. An idea please.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $A$ such that for all $n$, $\lVert x_n\rVert\geqslant \lVert A\rVert-n^{-1}$. Then for each $x^*\in B^*$ and each $n\geqslant 1$, since $x_n\in A$, 
$$
s\left(x^*\mid A\right)\geqslant \langle x^*,x_n\rangle,
$$
hence $$
\sup_{x^*\in B^*}s\left(x^*\mid A\right)\geqslant \sup_{x^*\in B^*}\langle x^*,x_n\rangle.
$$
Now, you probably know that as a corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem, $\sup_{x^*\in B^*}\langle x^*,x_n\rangle=\lVert x_n\rVert$ hence you can conclude.